# How to escape symbols entered in django admin to html representation

Tags: python, mysql, django, character-encoding, django-admin

I have a model that has a regular text field, that needs to be able to accept user pasted text data into it which may contain scientific symbols, specifically lowercase delta `δ`. The users will be entering the data through the model admin.

I'm using a mysql backend, and the encoding is set to Latin-1. Changing the DB encoding is not an option for me.

what i would like to do, for simplicity's sake, is have the admin form scrub the input text, much like sanitation or validation, but to escape the characters such as `δ` to their HTML representation,so that i can store them in the DB without having to convert to Unicode and then back again.

What utilities are available to do this? I've looked at `escape()` and `conditional_escape()`, but they do not seem to do what i want them to (not escape the special characters) and the `django.utils.encoding.force_text()` will encode everything, but my data will render as its Unicode representation if i do that.

The site runs on django 1.10 and python 2.7.x

any help or thoughts are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As part of the save method or view that receives the request.POST data, you can escape it, encode it to ascii with xmlcharrefreplace, and then decode it back from bytes to a string:

```
raw_str = "this is a string with δ problematic chars"
result = html.escape(raw_str).encode("ascii", "xmlcharrefreplace").decode()
print(result) # 'this is a string with &#948; problematic chars'
```

Gets the job done since you can't change the encoding, though not nearly as clean as just getting to live in UTF-8. Good luck!

Comment: Surely you don't need to do any encoding/decoding??  Why is the `POST` returning &#948; instead of the UTF-8 character??